# Python left shift (sign issue)

Tags: javascript, python, integer, signed, bit-shift

In this example I'm obtaining a positive number, but I need an expression in Python that gives the same result as in Javascript.

How can that negative result be obtained in Python?

**Python 2.7**

```
mv = 1732584193 << 5
```

Result:

> mv = 55442694176

`bin(mv)` gives `0b1100111010001010010001100000001`

**Javascript**

```
mv = 1732584193 << 5
```

Result:

> mv = -391880672

`mv.toString(2)` gives `-10111010110111001111111100000`

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1375897/707111

Comment: Thanks, I've already read and tried to shift the values directly returned from that functions, with the same results.

Comment: Don't shift the values returned from that function. Shift, *then* apply that function. You'll also need to mask it with `0xffffffff`.

Comment: You are right, thanks minitech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ctypes to do this:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> mv = ctypes.c_int32(1732584193)
>>> mv.value <<= 5
>>> mv
c_int(-391880672)
>>> bin(mv.value)
'-0b10111010110111001111111100000'
```

Comment: Thank you jterrace. Tough already pointed to the answer, your approach is the best fit to my script.