# Converting bitstring to 32-bit signed integer yields wrong result

Tags: python, python-2.7, bit

I am trying to solve a challenge on [this](https://www.codewars.com/kata/morse-encoding/train/python) site. I have everything correct except I can't properly convert a bitstring to its 32-bit signed integer representation.

For example I have this bitstring:

```
block = '10101010001000101110101000101110'
```

My own way of converting this bitstring to 32-bit signed integer: I partially remember from school that first bit is the sign bit. If it is 1 we have negative number and vice versa.

when I do this, it gives me the number in base 10. It just converts it to base 10:

```
int(block, 2) #yields 2854414894
```

I have tried excluding the first bit and convert remaining 31 length bitstring, after that checked the first bit to decide whether this is negative number or not:

```
int(block[1:32], 2) #yields 706931246
```

But the correct answer is `-1440552402`. What operation should I do to this bitstring to get this integer? Is it relevant if the byte order of the system is little endian or big endian? My system is little endian.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375897/how-to-get-the-signed-integer-value-of-a-long-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that the upper bit determines sign, but it's not a simple flag. Instead, the whole character of negative numbers is inverted. This is a positive number 1 (in 8 bits):

```
00000001
```

This is a negative 1:

```
11111111
```

The upshot is that addition and subtraction "wrap around". So 4 - 1 would be:

```
0100 - 0001 = 0011
```

And so 0 - 1 is the same as 1_0000_0000 - 1. The "borrow" just goes off the top of the integer.

The general way to "negate" a number is "invert the bits, add 1". This works both ways, so you can go from positive to negative and back.

In your case, use the leading '1' to detect whether negation is needed, then convert to int, then maybe perform the negation steps. Note, however, that because python's `int` **is not** a fixed-width value, there's a separate internal flag (a Python `int` is not a "32-bit" number, it's an arbitrary-precision integer, with a dynamically allocated representation stored in some fashion other than simple 2's complement).

```
block = '10101010001000101110101000101110'
asnum = int(block, 2)
if block[0] == '1':
    asnum ^= 0xFFFFFFFF
    asnum += 1
    asnum = -asnum

print(asnum)
```

Comment: It solved my problem. Thanks. However, why did we XORed `asnum`? Could you explain that too?

Comment: XORing the number with FFFF (all 1 bits) inverts the bits. 1 becomes 0, 0 becomes 1.

Comment: Ohh, I get it. It is one's complement. Coudln't we just use `~` operator for this?

Comment: You certainly could. Feel free!

Answer (score 4):

In python there's no size for integers, so you'll never get a negative value with a high order 1 bit.

To "emulate" 32-bit behaviour just do this, since your `2854414894` value is > `2**31-1` aka `0x7FFFFFFF`:

```
print(int(block[1:32], 2)-2**31)
```

you'll get

```
-1440552402
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check for when the input value is out of the positive range for 32 bit signed integers:

```
res = int(block, 2)
if res >= 2**31:
    res -= 2**32
```

So first you interpret the number as an *unsigned* number, but when you notice the sign bit was set ( >= 2^31 ), you subtract 2^32 so to get the negative number.