# How do I correctly pass uint32 to a Protobuf object in Python?

Tags: python, types, protocol-buffers

For quite a long time I can not find a solution to this problem on the Internet. **I must say that it is impossible to change the data type for a specific field, since the product has already been released and there is no way to replace the decoding of the Protobuf message or completely abandon Protobuf :(**

The problem is that the Protobuf data type, number 5, accepts only the standard Python int, which may be too large due to the fact that it is not an unsigned int.

**I tried using numpy. uint32 and ctypes. c_uint32, but both options end up being converted automatically to regular Python int and I get the error: "ValueError: Value out of range: 2902080034". I need to somehow fit in the 5th Protobuf data type the first 32 bits of UUID4 as a number.**

I hope for help, thank you in advance. Unfortunately, in my opinion, this may be a popular problem not described here before.

Comment: Why don't you show some code of what you have tried?

Comment: @PaulM. Assign a value to a field is literally =. The question is rather about data types and how to feed the type I need under the disguise of the standard Python int. I don't think it makes sense to write something like np.uint32(100), because everyone knows how it is done and there can be no problems in this part.

Answer (score 0):

Type [.proto uint32](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#scalar) corresponds to python [int](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/ints/), i.e. it has range -2147483648 through 2147483647.

One solution is to convert your unsigned 32 bit value to a signed one by:

```py
if (value & 0x80000000):
    value = -0x10000000 + value
```

The conversion is as suggested here:
[How to get the signed integer value of a long in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375897/how-to-get-the-signed-integer-value-of-a-long-in-python)